# Getting equal number of cells within rasterstack using R

Tags: raster, r, raster-calculator, terra

I have a `raster_stack` with 3 rasters. I made them the same resolution, extent, projection so that I could combine them into the stack. So, I expected each raster to have the same number of pixels. The stack looks like this

```
class      : RasterStack 
dimensions : 670, 407, 272690, 3  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 5000, 5000  (x, y)
extent     : -956367.5, 1078633, -943230.2, 2406770  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=aea +lat_0=37.5 +lon_0=-96 +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs 
names      : combined_raster_ar_f_spring, combined_raster_la_f_spring, combined_raster_tn_f_spring 
min values :               -4.406109e-08,                2.585209e-02,                2.956454e-02 
max values :                   1.0000000,                   0.9999818,                   0.9999999
```

However, when I calculate `cellStats(raster_stack, sum)` I receive different number of pixels:

```
combined_raster_ar_f_spring combined_raster_la_f_spring combined_raster_tn_f_spring 
                   154113.1                    181287.8                    179037.4
```

The images look like this, all scaled from 0-1.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Because images are scaled from 0-1, I presume I would have to fill a certain number of NAs with 1s in order for the 1st and 3rd image to have as many pixels as the 2nd.

Is there an easy way to increase the the number of pixels in the 1st and 3rd raster so they equal the number of pixels in the 2nd raster within the stack?

I do not know of a function in `raster` or `terra` to do this.

Comment: Each layer in the stack *does* have the same number of pixels. `cellStats(s, sum)` is adding up the *values* of the pixels.